# disable auto rounding

Tags: php, mysql, rounding

I have downloaded Stock Inventory Management
PHP Stock Inventory Management System - POS

that located here :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/stock-inventory-management/

my issue is how to disable auto rounding that is enabled by default for numbers
that are decimal eg: 4.56 ->5.00 
what i want is to disbale it and save the number as is: 4.56-4.56

Comment: the reason is because they may be using function like number_format or ceil to display the numeric  value , you can use sprintf($val) or intval or floor to prevent rounding

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but i have searched about these functions for more than 8 hours with no benifit, can you help me to trace the source of this issue ,and this project created using phpmaker

Comment: Please consider following the site policy recommendations : you should post a small program exposing the issue, rather than giving a link to your whole project, the later being subject to changes, and probably not an easy to understand example for people using the site.